# Как установить мета теги для отправленного файла в express и возможно ли это?

Tags: javascript, html, express, seo

Ниже код, это стандартный роутер экспресса. Он просто отдает статичный json файл. Возникла идея добавить браузерные мета теги: title, description для этого роута. Возможно ли это?

```
router.get('/static/data.json', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('.', 'public/new_data.json'));
});
```

Comment: Так вам в итоге на клиенте нужен JSON или HTML? Упомянутые теги - это HTML-сущности.

Comment: _браузерные мета теги: title, description_ не имеют смысла для скачиваемого файлы